# No valid schema provided for processing

Tags: cloud-document-ai

I'm trying to make a nodejs project to extract data from invoices using Cloud Document AI API. I have copied the code provided on google doc as follows:

```js
/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment these variables before running the sample.
 */
const projectId = <my project id>;
const location = us; // Format is 'us' or 'eu'
const processorId = <my processor id>// Create processor in Cloud Console
const filePath = "./testImage.png";

const { DocumentProcessorServiceClient } =
  require("@google-cloud/documentai").v1;

// Instantiates a client
// apiEndpoint regions available: eu-documentai.googleapis.com, us-documentai.googleapis.com (Required if using eu based processor)
// const client = new DocumentProcessorServiceClient({apiEndpoint: 'eu-documentai.googleapis.com'});
const client = new DocumentProcessorServiceClient();

async function quickstart() {
  // The full resource name of the processor, e.g.:
  // projects/project-id/locations/location/processor/processor-id
  // You must create new processors in the Cloud Console first
  const name = `projects/${projectId}/locations/${location}/processors/${processorId}`;

  // Read the file into memory.
  const fs = require("fs").promises;
  const imageFile = await fs.readFile(filePath);

  // Convert the image data to a Buffer and base64 encode it.
  const encodedImage = Buffer.from(imageFile).toString("base64");

  // add a valid schema f
  const request = {
    name,
    rawDocument: {
      content: encodedImage,
      mimeType: "image/png",
    },
  };

  // Recognizes text entities in the PDF document

  const [result] = await client.processDocument(request);
  const { document } = result;

  // Get all of the document text as one big string
  const { text } = document;

  console.log(text)
}

quickstart();
```

but, when I run the code I receive the following error:

```
"node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: No valid schema provided for processing."
```

In other notes of the error object I also have:

`"note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'"`

I'm stuck on this problem I don't even know what to try to solve it.

I tried to change the field `"mimeType"` from `"application/json"` to `"image/png"` thinking it was a problem regarding the file format passed. Nothing. If I access the processor from the console and submit the file for testing it works fine.

I put the breaking code into a try-catch block:

```js
try {
    const [result] = await client.processDocument(request);
    const { document } = result;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
    return
  }
```

and I get this error:

```
"[14544:0115/143509.312:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to move the cache: Access is denied. (0x5)
[14544:0115/143509.312:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(205)] Unable to create cache"
```